# React: How can I render a list without keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this `json` and I was wondering if there is a way to render a list without having to specify a key.

Here's what I tried:

```
import * as data from "./file.json";

const nameComponent = props => {
  const names = data.locale.names

  return(
    names.map = name => {
      <Item>
        <IdName>{name.id}</IdName>
        <FirstName>{name.firstName}</FirstName>
        <LastName>{name.lastName}</LastName>
      </Item>
  )
}
```

I can also just add the keys but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Why am I getting this error even if I specified the keys?

Like this:

```
return(
  names.map = name => {
    <Item key={name.id}>
      <IdName>{name.id}</IdName>
      <FirstName>{name.firstName}</FirstName>
      <LastName>{name.lastName}</LastName>
    </Item>
)
```

EDIT: I have tried the answers below, none of them worked.

The json looks like this:

```
"items": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Alan",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Something"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: your ids are unique ?

Comment: I don't think you want to render without keys. They're used to help react perform better

Comment: you are returning a function !? Not a list.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know about that, I have added the full code. Do you think this is a function?

Comment: I think, `name => {...}` is a function, and `names.map = name => {...}` is assigning the function to `names.map`. No execution in sight. and `return a=b` is identical to `a=b; return b;` So, returning the function.

Comment: Despite the question being closed as "duplicate", the problem was not in `key` (it was just a warning, not an error, after all), but in the `return` statement of `nameComponent` (and BTW your React components should be *PascalCased*, not *camelCased*).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return(
      names.map( name => {
        <Item key={name.id + name}>
          <IdName>{name.id}</IdName>
          <FirstName>{name.firstName}</FirstName>
          <LastName>{name.lastName}</LastName>
        </Item>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't look right. Try

```
return(
  names.map(name => (
    <Item key={name.id}>the rest of the template...
  )
)
```

Comment: `i` is `undefined`, you meant `map((name,i) => ...)`, I believe

Comment: Ah right, I copied-pasted the wrong line.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, perhaps, it's from my json?

Comment: Did you replace your curly braces `{` with `(`? Because with `/* ... */ => {` and no explicit return statement, the function returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return(
  names.map = (name, index) => {
    <Item key={index}>
      <IdName>{name.id}</IdName>
      <FirstName>{name.firstName}</FirstName>
      <LastName>{name.lastName}</LastName>
    </Item>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys need to be uniq, we should not use index as the key , I think your id of each profile is similar to index values like 1,2,3. So it is better user keys like below

```
return (names.map = name => {
<Item key={`NamesItem-${name.id}`}>
  <IdName>{name.id}</IdName>
  <FirstName>{name.firstName}</FirstName>
  <LastName>{name.lastName}</LastName>
</Item>)
```